# Atomic operations on `unique_ptr`

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic, smart-pointers

`std::shared_ptr` [has specializations for atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) like `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` and family, but I cannot find documentation on equivalent specializations for `std::unique_ptr`. Are there any? If not, why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there no standard atomic functions for `std::unique_ptr`.

I did find an argument for why not in [Atomic Smart Pointers(N4058)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4058.pdf) by Herb Sutter

> Lawrence Crowl responded to add:
>
> One of the reasons that shared_ptr locking is the way it is is to avoid a situation in which we weaken the precondition on the atomic template parameter that it be trivial, and hence have no risk of deadlock.
>
> That said, we could weaken the requirement so that the argument type only needs to be lockfree, or perhaps only non-recursively locking.
>
> However, while trivial makes for reasonably testable traits, I see no effective mechanism to test for the weaker property.

That proposal has been assigned to the Concurrency Subgroup and has no disposition as of yet.  You can check the status at [JTC1/SC22/WG21 - Papers 2014](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/) mailing2014-07

Comment: That reference gives reason to why (pre c++17) `std::atomic<T>`  doesn't work with smart pointers, but not why there are no  overloads of e.g. `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` for std::unique_ptr, while there are for std::shared_ptr

Comment: In the mean time, N4058 has been revised as N4162. You can find it at the links above in mailing2014-10.

Answer (score 23):

The reason that it is possible to provide an atomic instance of `std::shared_ptr` and it is not possible to do so for `std::unique_ptr` is hinted at in their signature. Compare:

- `std::shared_ptr<T>` vs
- `std::unique_ptr<T, D>` where `D` is the type of the Deleter.

---

`std::shared_ptr` needs to allocate a control-block where the strong and weak count are kept, so type-erasure of the deleter came at a trivial cost (a simply slightly larger control-block).

As a result, the layout of `std::shared_ptr<T>` is generally similar to:

```
template <typename T>
struct shared_ptr {
    T* _M_ptr;
    SomeCounterClass<T>* _M_counters;
};
```

And it is possible to atomically perform the exchange of those two pointers.

---

`std::unique_ptr` has a zero-overhead policy; using a `std::unique_ptr` should not incur any overhead compared to using a raw pointer.

As a result, the layout of `std::unique_ptr<T, D>` is generally similar to:

```
template <typename T, typename D = default_delete<T>>
struct unique_ptr {
    tuple<T*, D> _M_t;
};
```

Where the `tuple` uses EBO (Empty Base Optimization) so that whenever D is zero-sized then `sizeof(unique_ptr<T>) == sizeof(T*)`.

However, in the cases where `D` is NOT zero-sized, the implementation boils down to:

```
template <typename T, typename D = default_delete<T>>
struct unique_ptr {
    T* _M_ptr;
    D _M_del;
};
```

This `D` is the kicker here; it is not possible, in general, to guarantee that `D` can be exchange in an atomic fashion without relying on mutexes.

Therefore, it is not possible to provide an `std::atomic_compare_exchange*` suite of specialized routine for the generic `std::unique_ptr<T, D>`.

Note that the standard does not even guarantee that `sizeof(unique_ptr<T>) == sizeof(T*)` AFAIK, though it's a common optimization.

Comment: Well it seems like it _would_ be possible, but in the case of deleters that are too large, you'd just have to give up `is_lock_free == true` for that instantiation, like any other too-big-to-CAS object.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: It's more complicated than that, because C++ allows customizing the move constructor/move assignment, so a simple bitwise exchange is not sufficient. This could, of course, *also* be detected.

Comment: You first say: "std::unique_ptr has a zero-overhead policy; using a std::unique_ptr should not incur any overhead compared to using a raw pointer." Then you say "Note that the standard does not even guarantee that sizeof(unique_ptr<T>) == sizeof(T*) AFAIK, though it's a common optimization." Are they contradictory?

Comment: @xuhdev No, they are not. The C++ standard is concerned about _semantics_, and leaves performance as a quality of implementation detail. In practice, implementers (and the users) are very concerned about performance, and therefore implementations take great care of ensuring that the Zero-Overhead goal is achieved. Since it's not strictly guaranteed, however, it leaves room for _instrumentation_, typically when debugging flags are specified, to help catch errors.

Answer (score 7):

Be careful, sharing a modifiable `unique_ptr` between threads rarely makes sense, even if the pointer itself was atomic. If its contents changes, how can other threads know about it? They can't.

Consider this example:

```
unique_ptr<MyObject> p(new MyObject);

// Thread A
auto ptr = p.get();
if (ptr) {
    ptr->do_something();
}

// Thread B
p.reset();
```

How can Thread A avoid using a dangling pointer after calling `p.get()`?

If you want to share an object between threads, use `shared_ptr` which has reference counting exactly for this purpose.

---

If you *really* wanted it, you can always roll your own `atomic_unique_ptr`, something along the lines (simplified):

```
#pragma once
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class atomic_unique_ptr
{
  using pointer = T *;
  std::atomic<pointer> ptr;
public:
  constexpr atomic_unique_ptr() noexcept : ptr() {}
  explicit atomic_unique_ptr(pointer p) noexcept : ptr(p) {}
  atomic_unique_ptr(atomic_unique_ptr&& p) noexcept : ptr(p.release()) {}
  atomic_unique_ptr& operator=(atomic_unique_ptr&& p) noexcept { reset(p.release()); return *this; }
  atomic_unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<T>&& p) noexcept : ptr(p.release()) {}
  atomic_unique_ptr& operator=(std::unique_ptr<T>&& p) noexcept { reset(p.release()); return *this; }

  void reset(pointer p = pointer()) { auto old = ptr.exchange(p); if (old) delete old; }
  operator pointer() const { return ptr; }
  pointer operator->() const { return ptr; }
  pointer get() const { return ptr; }
  explicit operator bool() const { return ptr != pointer(); }
  pointer release() { return ptr.exchange(pointer()); }
  ~atomic_unique_ptr() { reset(); }
};

template<class T>
class atomic_unique_ptr<T[]> // for array types
{
  using pointer = T *;
  std::atomic<pointer> ptr;
public:
  constexpr atomic_unique_ptr() noexcept : ptr() {}
  explicit atomic_unique_ptr(pointer p) noexcept : ptr(p) {}
  atomic_unique_ptr(atomic_unique_ptr&& p) noexcept : ptr(p.release()) {}
  atomic_unique_ptr& operator=(atomic_unique_ptr&& p) noexcept { reset(p.release()); return *this; }
  atomic_unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<T>&& p) noexcept : ptr(p.release()) {}
  atomic_unique_ptr& operator=(std::unique_ptr<T>&& p) noexcept { reset(p.release()); return *this; }

  void reset(pointer p = pointer()) { auto old = ptr.exchange(p); if (old) delete[] old; }
  operator pointer() const { return ptr; }
  pointer operator->() const { return ptr; }
  pointer get() const { return ptr; }
  explicit operator bool() const { return ptr != pointer(); }
  pointer release() { return ptr.exchange(pointer()); }
  ~atomic_unique_ptr() { reset(); }
};
```

NB: The code provided in this post is hereby released into Public Domain.

Comment: It actually would make perfectly sense: It is actually a common lockfree pattern to create an object on the heap and - once you are done with it - storing a pointer to it in a shared variable. Now, if any thread wants to access the object, it first has to atomically exchange that pointer with a nullptr and storing the pointer back once that thread is finished. That way you ensure that ever only one thread has access to an object at the same time.

Comment: E.g.because one is a producer and one is a consumer (or you even have multiple consumers). Then you WANT to transfer ownership to  whoever gets the pointer. In any case: assuming you have an atomic unique_ptr then I don't see how it simplifies things when you handle lifetime separately from visibility / accessibility.

Comment: Assigning ::get() to a lvalue (a value that lives longer than your current instruction) is a bad idea, as it kind of destroys the advantage of using smart pointers.

Comment: @morty smart pointers are a tool for lifetime management, but it is still up to the developer to reason about object lifetimes in his/her program, unfortunately. Using raw pointers within the lifetime of an object is still a perfectly valid pattern. It is even normal to dangle pointers, as long as they are no dereferenced outside the lifetime of the object being pointed at.

Comment: @rustix: Ok, rereading your code I think your example got me off track. If I understand you right, you assume that std_unique is shared between the two threads (I was assuming, that the OP does things right and passes it back and forth). In that case the same issue arises if you do `p->do_something_long()` (No extra raw reference).
Yet under this assumption, a shared_ptr does not help in itself. You need a local copy of the "global" shared pointer while you use it.
Note: `do_something_long()`is only to highlight the issue. As it's concurrency it does not matter how long the method takes.