# How to safely transfer ownership of atomic raw pointer to move only object to another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

Need to enqueue a `Task` (non copyable, only moveable), from a `Enqueue` function and then delegate the processing to a `Process` function on a separate thread.

`Enqueue` function is called by multiple threads.

Yes, this can be done by a queue, but as of now I only need one `task`. `compare_and_exchange` looks better than a full fledged multi-producer-single-consumer queue or a lock on enqueue single-producer-single-consumer queue.

```
// multiple enqueuers
bool Enqueue(Task task) {
    auto task_ptr = new Task{std::move(task)};
    Task* expected = nullptr;
    while(!this->enqueud_task_.compare_exchange_strong(expected, task_ptr)) {
        if (!somecondition) {
            delete task_ptr;
            return false; 
        }
    }
    return true;        
}

// process
void Process() {
    auto task = this->enqueud_task_.load();
    if (task) {
        auto t = task;
        this->do_store(std::move(*t)); // Store the moved object to internal data structure.
        delete t;
        this->enqueud_task_ = nullptr; 
    }
}
```

The problem is I am allocating a new `Task` which is moved from the original task. This causes me to manually call `delete`.

`std::atomic<std::unique_ptr<Task>>` is not a valid type, nor is `std::atomic<Task>` as Task is not trivially copyable.

Comment: [Relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067675/atomic-operations-on-unique-ptr)

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yes I had checked that question. I was trying to see if there can be any workaround in my situation if I cannot declare a `std::atomic<std::unique_ptr<Task>>`. Even something that automatically deletes the task_ptr on out of scope would go a long way.

Comment: May be atomic shared_ptr?

Comment: @SergeyA Would be better if i can avoid shared ptr as it will keep a reference count structure allocated.

Comment: @SergeyA @MaLanghof I believe the crux of the problem stems from the fact that `compare_and_exchange` doesn't allow move only on success feature. If I pass to compare_and_exchange the `desired` value as `std::move(task)` , the task is forever lost if `compare_and_exchange` fails. Then agains, atomic itself doesn't support noncopyable types.

Comment: CAS is no except, you could do `std::unique_ptr task_ptr = …` and `compare_exchange_strong(expected, task_ptr.get())`, then call `release` on success

Comment: @PasserBy I guess `unique_ptr::release` is a better way that the current method.