# Does accessing a pointer of std::unique_ptr type apply memory ordering?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, unique-ptr

Let's say we have a global object of type `Wrapper` which has `std::unique_ptr<MyObject> m_pUnique` member which is not nullptr. Then `m_pUnique` is set to nullptr in thread 1, so a destructor of `MyObject` is called, and then the thread exits. After thread 1 has exited, thread 2 calls destructor of a Wrapper object. The questions are:

1. Will thread 2 see that `m_pUnique` is nullptr after thread 1 has exited? 
   (I heard that some memory ordering happens when thread exits (thread 1 is this case), but not sure whether thread 2 that reads the m_pUnique pointer value (and does NOT read its inner object value) will see the new pointer value. )
2. If thread 2 does not see that `m_pUnique` is now nullptr, is there a possibility, that a destructor of `m_pUnique`'s  `MyObject` will be called again?

A simplified code example:

```
    class Wrapper
    {
    public:
      std::unique_ptr<MyObject> m_pUnique;
    }    

    //Global var created somewhere e.g. in thread 0
    Wrapper* someWrapper = new Wrapper();     
    someWrapper->m_pUnique.reset(new MyObject);
    //...

    //sets m_pUnique to nullptr, which calls MyObject's destructor and then threads exits
    Thread1Func() 
    {
      someWrapper.m_pUnique = nullptr; 
    }  

    //delete Wrapper object after thread 1 has exited  
    Thread2Func()
    {
      delete someWrapper;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is unique\_ptr thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482580/is-unique-ptr-thread-safe)

Comment: Use unique_ptr with custom deleter instead of using a thread for deleting. Also `someWrapper.reset(new MyObject);` should read as `someWrapper->m_pUnique.reset(new MyObject());`

Comment: Related: [Atomic operations on `unique_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35067675/580083).

Comment: @RichardCritten not really - the post you suggested relates to accessing the object "underneath" the pointer. My question is more about "if pointer value (==adress it points to, not actual object pointer points to) has changed in thread1, will the change of pointer value be visible in thread2 (especially in destructor), or memory fences are required?

Comment: @seccpur that is demonstrative example from a huge project, where deleting in another thread is required. Thus, a deleter (custom or native) will still be called in a separate thread. 
Thank you, edited the code to "->m_pUnique", missed that

Comment: It isn't clear what access patterns are expected. Do you reset or delete stuff at the same time? Do you do a reset of a smart ptr while some other thread is using it?

Answer (score 0):

If thread 2 has been reading m_pUnique from someWrapper, then it is not guaranteed (no barrier implied) that it will spot that m_pUnique changed unless the member is marked volatile, or made atomic.

However, different code which has to re-inspect the object is run when the destructor is called, so the destructor will see that m_pUnique is already nullptr assuming that your CPU supports cache and core coherency. This prevents the target object getting double-destructed.

Without coherency, and additional synchronisation primitives, you're SOL as there are no thread safety guarantees in std::unique_ptr<>.

**Edit**: I should also note that, when you have multiple threads accessing an object to write (delete is a write operation), you should be using std::mutex anyway, making most of the question moot as all access to the shared object needs to be guarded for correctness.

Comment: With respect to `volatile`: _"...This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution..."_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: Aye, true @richard-critten, however the primary point of noting volatile here is strictly to do with forcing the compiler to always re-read the member by using it to mean "this can change at any time so can't be cached", not to imply any thread safety results from its use.

Comment: "assuming that your CPU supports cache and core coherency." - does this apply to all x86-x64 architectures?

Comment: All arch well supported by a normal C++ compiler is going to have coherent caches, and it would a pain to implement C++ on any arch that doesn't have those (to the point that normal MT code is probably going to run so inefficiently on such uncommon arch, it may not even worth introducing std thread primitive support)

Comment: @curiousguy it does happen on some embedded platforms, and as they don't run an OS kernel, it is actually not a problem (though they also don't support threading as such) especially as each core is running unique firmware.

Comment: @DX-MON The point is that volatile semantics is almost never sufficient to accomplish what programmers expect in MT code, and what's necessary to accomplish it almost always makes volatile useless.

Comment: @curiousguy that may be so (and I don't disagree), I'm merely making the point that you cannot brush them off out of hand just because they don't apply well to desktop - they apply in other fields C++ applies in, so it's worth taking note.

Comment: @DX-MON They apply to which other non desktop platform more often than on the desktop?

Comment: @curiousguy: volatile applies in any situation you are either in an OS kernel itself, but below the scheduler, or, more importantly, when you have no OS at all.

The bulk of embedded: still makes sense in this case to use primitives such as std::unique_ptr<> to ensure the lifetimes of your vars (correctness by construction) but if you are either directly interacting with hardware through those pointers, or you have shared memory between processors and each is either running different code, or is simply a different architecture.. volatile. It specifically tells the compiler "never cache".

Comment: The point I am making is not that volatile gives you MT-correct code (as addressed in my answer), but that it allows your thread to "see" the write the other thread (or hardware, or processor) did as it forces the compiler to re-read the memory housing that pointer rather than re-use the value it read and cached in a local processor register. That is the point of volatile. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

If in a thread you see an apparently magically changing value of class instance (that is not specifically designed for thread communication), it can only be the result of a modification by another thread that was not properly ordered with respect to all threads that might read the object, and **the behavior is not defined: the compiler is not required to be able to handle these cases; anything can happen**. (Volatile or not volatile.)

The fact that it's an instance of a so called "smart pointer" type makes no difference.